# ClassNotFoundException While Deserializing in OSGi Bundles

Tags: java, osgi, classnotfoundexception, jgroups

In an OSGi bundle (called `net.beaconcontroller.cluster`), I have a `org.jgroups.blocks.ReplicatedHashMap` of type `<Long, net.beaconcontroller.cluster.ControllerInfo>`. The problem is, during dispatching (that is, deserialization of `ControllerInfo` on the remote end) JGroups complains with `ClassNotFoundException`. (Stack trace is attached.) Adding

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Cluster.class.getClassLoader())
```

line to the startUp() method of the `net.beaconcontroller.cluster` bundle did have no effects. What might I be missing?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.beaconcontroller.cluster.ControllerInfo
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jgroups.blocks.ReplicatedHashMap.setState(ReplicatedHashMap.java:540) ~[na:na]
        at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.handleUpEvent(MessageDispatcher.java:497) ~[na:na]
        at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:558) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Could you move ControllerInfo into a separate fragment bundle setting JGroups as the fragment host? That way JGroups should be able to see the ControllerInfo class during deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add in your bundle's MANIFEST.MF:

```
Import-Package: net.beaconcontroller.cluster
```